# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed (headless chrome)

Tags: java, maven, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

I am running headless chrome on centos, with headless chrome version 2.38, and google-chrome-stable version 67.0

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", driverPath);
    log.warn("chrome driver path is : {}", driverPath);
    List<String> options = proxyConfig.getChromeOptions();
    ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
      chromeOptions.addArguments(options);
    Map<String, String> capabilites = proxyConfig.getCapabilities();
    if(MapUtils.isNotEmpty(capabilites)) {
      for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : capabilites.entrySet()) {
        chromeOptions.setCapability(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
      }
    }
    // proxy configuration
    /*Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
    proxy.setProxyType(Proxy.ProxyType.MANUAL);
    proxy.setHttpProxy(proxyConfig.getProxyHost());
    proxy.setSocksUsername(proxyConfig.getProxyUsername());
    proxy.setSocksPassword(proxyConfig.getProxyPassword());
    chromeOptions.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);*/
    log.warn("chorme driver created ");
    return new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

chrome options:

```
 "--headless", 
        "----disable-gpu", 
        "--ignore-certificate-errors", 
        "window-size=1920,1080"
```

It is giving below given error message at last line :

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.552522 (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb),platform=Linux 4.9.77blibli.com x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 60.11 seconds
Build info: version: ‘3.6.0’, revision: ‘6fbf3ec767’, time: ‘2017-09-27T15:28:36.4Z’
System info: host: ‘csrapp-02’, ip: ‘127.0.1.1’, os.name: ‘Linux’, os.arch: ‘amd64’, os.version: ‘4.9.77dwdwde.com’, java.version: ‘1.8.0_101’
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
```

i have verified chrome, and chromedriver version, it is compatible. Couldn't understand why it is not running on centos?
Same code works fine on mac

pom

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
      <version>3.12.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **WebBrowser** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session.

As you are using ***Headless Chrome on CentOS*** it is worth to mention that as per the discussion [**Getting Started with Headless Chrome**](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome) **`--disable-gpu`** is `Temporarily needed if running on Windows.`

```
--disable-gpu \                # Temporarily needed if running on Windows.
```

However, your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=2.38*
- You are using *chrome=67.0*
- Your *Selenium Client* version is ***3.6.0*** of *2017-09-27T15:28:36.4Z* which is almost *a year* older.
- Your *JDK version* is **1.8.0_101** which is pretty *ancient*.

So there is a clear mismatch between the **JDK v8u101** , **Selenium Client v3.6.0** , **ChromeDriver v2.38** and the **Chrome Browser v67.0**

### Solution

- Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels [**JDK 8u171**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).
- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.12.0**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [**ChromeDriver v2.40**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version between ***Chrome v66-68*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.40 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.40/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test`.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Tried with selenium 3.12.0, chrome driver 2.40, chrome 67, didn't work, facing same issue.

Comment: @BhagwatiMalav Using JDK or Maven? `chrome driver 3.12.0`?

Comment: i am using maven. Updated my comment, please check it again.

Comment: added relevant dependency to the post.

Comment: One more question, it it recommended to use centos with selenium, headless chrome ?

Comment: Of-coarse yes, any _OS_ any _flavor_

Comment: Added a couple of clean-up steps. Let me know the status

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173076/discussion-between-bhagwati-malav-and-debanjanb).